# Move frame off the edges of the picture

Tags: html, css

I have pictures on a page, and when I hover over them, a blue border appears

[image]

[image]

But this frame appears abruptly, but I would like it to gradually shrink from the edges of the picture and stand in the same place, can I do this?

Here are my styles

```css
.article-block__img-wrapper {
     position: relative;
}
 .article-block__img-wrapper span {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
}
 .article-block__img-wrapper span::before {
     display: block;
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
     transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
     outline: 1px solid #4F8EFF;
     outline-offset: -10px;
     opacity: 0;
}
 .article-block__img-wrapper:hover span::before {
     opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-block">
   <div class="article-block__img-wrapper">
      <span>
         <img class="block-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="" title="">
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using LESS or another CSS pre-processor, it's worth either including the tag for that processor or just posting the generated CSS. Also, including the HTML is always helpful for style questions as it means we don't have to guess the structure.

Comment: @DBS understood you, added to the post

Comment: You can use css transition on position to do this.
Transition is for each property. If you want a global interpolation you can use `transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out` but it better to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to expand on your current animation using `transition`.

`transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, outline-offset 0.2s ease-in-out;`

You can edit the timing/easing independently for each style.

Then apply `outline-offset: -10px;` inside your hover styles.

Functional Codepen example of the below code (Since I don't think Stack snippets support LESS) [available here](https://codepen.io/DBSquirrel/pen/wvraZjb).

```
<div class="article-block">
  <div class="article-block__img-wrapper">
    <span>
      <img class="block-img" src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="" title="">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.article-block__img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    &::before {
      display: block;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, outline-offset 0.2s ease-in-out;
      outline: 1px solid #4f8eff;
      outline-offset: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

  &:hover {
    span::before {
      opacity: 1;
      outline-offset: -10px;
    }
  }
}
```